# vcs_info, proper config in zsh?

Tags: zsh, cvs

I've recently installed zsh and took the time to configure it properly, quick overview of methods tried:

**setopt prompt_subst**
Use prompt_subst so we can simply use the vcs_info variables and they'll be updated during run-time.

It works, with colours, and it shouldn't break anything trying to modify the PS1. however I can't seem to figure out what the downsides are for having it enabled?

**psvar**
Use a psvar to substitute the command line, works, but messes up on colours.

*update PS1 every precmd*
Works fine, but anything trying to modify PS1 fails as it gets reset. Could be fixed with hacks but it's too ugly/fragile IMO, so skip this one.

--

So to sum it up:

1. What downsides are there to having prompt_subst enabled?
2. Is there any way to make the colours work with psvar

If prompt_subst has significant downsides then 2 would be the best alternative if at all possible, 3 is a bit fragile so rather not use that.

**The relevant part of my .zshrc**

```
...

autoload -Uz vcs_info

# Needs to be enabled for the prompt to change
setopt prompt_subst

# Formats
VCS_FORMAT="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}(%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}%b%{$reset_color%}"
VCS_APPEND="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%})%{$reset_color%}"
VCS_NORMAL_FORMAT="${VCS_FORMAT}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}:%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%8.8i%{$reset_color%}${VCS_APPEND}"
VCS_ACTION_FORMAT="${VCS_FORMAT}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}:%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[red]%}%a%{$reset_color%}${VCS_APPEND}"

zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git hg svn 
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' get-revision true

zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats $VCS_NORMAL_FORMAT 
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats $VCS_ACTION_FORMAT

precmd () {
    vcs_info

    PS1_STR=""
    PS1_STR="${PS1_STR}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%m%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}]%{$reset_color%}" #hostname
    PS1_STR="${PS1_STR}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%n%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}]%{$reset_color%}"  #user
    PS1_STR="${PS1_STR}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%1~%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}]%{$reset_color%}" #folder
    PS1_STR="${PS1_STR}${vcs_info_msg_0_}\$ "                                                                                             #branch/end
}   

export PS1='${PS1_STR}'

...
```